# Can't get Intern to run Node.js Module

Tags: intern

I am trying to test Intern to see if it would be a good fit for a testing framework. I am trying to test the following code in Intern.

```
var HelloWorld;

HelloWorld = (function () {

  function HelloWorld (name) {
    this.name = name || "N/A";
  }

  HelloWorld.prototype.printHello = function() {
    console.log('Hello, ' + this.name);
  };

  HelloWorld.prototype.changeName = function(name) {
    if (name === null || name === undefined) {
      throw new Error('Name is required');
    }
    this.name = name;
  };

  return HelloWorld;

})();

exports = module.exports = HelloWorld;
```

The file is located in 'js-test-projects/node/lib/HelloWorld.js' and Intern is located at 'js-test-projects/intern'. I am using the 1.0.0 branch of Intern. Whenever I try to include the file and run the test I don't get any output after "Defaulting to console reporter". Here is the test file.

```
define([
  'intern!tdd',
  'intern/chai!assert',
  'dojo/node!../lib/HelloWorld'
], function (tdd, assert, HelloWorld) {
  console.log(HelloWorld);
});
```

Comment: For someone not familiar with node.js, this sounded like an internship posting :)

Comment: I hate when I can't get my intern to run what I want.

Answer (score 7):

**1. Assuming the following directory structure (based on the question):**

```
js-test-projects/
    node/
        lib/
            HelloWorld.js   - `HelloWorld` Node module
        tests/
            HelloWorld.js   - Tests for `HelloWorld`
            intern.js       - Intern configuration file
    intern/
```

**2. Your Intern configuration file should contain info on the `node` package and any suites to run:**

```js
// ...

// Configuration options for the module loader
loader: {
    // Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment
    packages: [ 'node' ]
},

// Non-functional test suite(s) to run
suites: [ 'node/tests/HelloWorld' ]

// ...
```

**3. Your test file should load `HelloWorld` using Intern's version of Dojo, like this:**

```js
define([
    'intern!tdd',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'intern/dojo/node!./node/lib/HelloWorld.js'
], function (tdd, assert, HelloWorld) {
    console.log(HelloWorld);
});
```

**Note:** You don't *have* to use Intern's version of Dojo to load the `HelloWorld` node module in this AMD test, it is just a convenient way to do so. If you have some other AMD plugin that node-requires a node module, that's perfectly fine.

**4. Finally, to run the tests in a Node.js environment, use Intern's `client.js` node runner by issuing the following command from within the `intern` directory:**

```
node client.js config=node/tests/intern
```

Comment: Note that if your Node module is already inside a resolvable `node_modules` directory then you just use `intern/dojo/node!node/lib/HelloWorld`.