# Replacing Chai Assertion Library in Intern

Tags: intern

Now that I've gotten Intern to run some tests, I would like to replace the Chai assertion library with expect.js library. [Expect.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/expect.js/) is a Node module that I've downloaded to my project using NPM. I've been looking at the following resources to piece together how to import the module using the dojo/node loader plugin provided by Intern, but I haven't quite the hang of it. I'm either using loader.packages incorrectly, or not using the correct path in my test file to include the module.

[Can't get Intern to run Node.js Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466115/cant-get-intern-to-run-node-js-module)

[dojo/node](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/node.html)

AMD API Wiki re: Packages

1. **My project hierarchy (if there is a best practice, or better way, for setting up my project with node modules, I can easily change the hierarchy)**

   ```
   APEFIntern/
       apeform/
           lib/
               sinon.js           - Mocking library
           node_modules/
               expect/
                   expect.js      - Node package
           test/
               intern.js          - Intern configuration
               spec_inwf.js       - Tests for inwf.js
           inwf.js                - Code to test
       intern/
   ```
2. **Intern configuration file**

   ```
   // ...

   loader: {
       // Pretty sure I need to register the package for the loader, not I'm not positive on the correct path to use.
       //packages: [ 'apeform/node_modules/expect' ]
       packages: [ 'apeform' ]
       //packages: [ 'expect' ]
   },

   // Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
   suites: [ 'apeform/test/spec_inwf' ],

   // ...
   ```
3. **Test file - I've tried different ways of referencing the node module, based upon comments in another question.**

   ```
   define([
       'intern!bdd',
       //'intern/chai!expect',
       //'intern/dojo/node!expect',
       //'intern/dojo/node!./apeform/node_modules/expect/expect'
       'intern/dojo/node!apeform/node_modules/expect',
       'apeform/lib/sinon.js',
       'apeform/inwf.js'
   ], function (bdd, expect) {
       with (bdd) {
           // Tests ...
   });
   ```

I'm trying to replace the assert library present in Intern so that I can run my tests against IE 6. I know there is the Geezer branch of Intern for IE 6-8, but it looks like the assertion library is the only difference between the branches and I prefer the expects syntax over assert.

Answer (score 1):

Expect.js installs to a folder that includes the ".js".

Try using `'intern/dojo/node!./apeform/node_modules/expect.js'` with the setup mentioned above.